# hidden door twitter button behaves wrongly in IE

Tags: button, twitter, focus, hidden, sliding

I want to implement a twitter button concept on my page but I have issues with it in IE 10 and 11 while in Chrome, Firefox and Opera it works perfectly. 
In IE it's like when the doors slide and the button is revealed, it takes the focus away from the doors which act as if the mouse has been moved away and they start closing.

Someone was suggesting somewhere to somehow place it in a container big enough for the max size (with doors open), but I don't know how to do this. I am kinda new to this.

This is a link to something similar that somehow it works in IE (I believe a solution from this could be identified)
http://codepen.io/SaraSoueidan/pen/rxzkn

I would really appreciate any kind of help in making my codepen below work in IE:
http://codepen.io/hillfingerr/pen/jJzbs

Kind regards!